# jQuery's blur() and selector

Tags: jquery, blur

I'm trying to create a new div each time a text field contained in the last div loses focus, but a new div is added only when the text field in the first div loses focus (instead of the last).

Here's my code:

```
    $(function() {
          $(':text:last').blur(function() {
            $('<div class="line"><span>data: </span><input type="text"/></div>')
            .appendTo($('#lineStack'));
        });
    }); 

HTML:

<div id="lineStack">
    <div class="line">
        <span>data: </span><input type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answered: Thanks Nick! Your answer worked. I've been trying to mark your post as answer but it's not working. Don't know why :)

Comment: Edit your comment and wrap the HTML tags in backticks (`\`<like this/>\``) -- this will prevent the system from stripping them out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this instead (requires jQuery 1.4+, otherwise `blur` bubble isn't handled):

```
$(function() { 
  $(':text:last').live('blur', function() { 
    $('#lineStack').append('<div class="line"><span>data: </span><input type="text"/></div>'); 
  }); 
});
```

Your current selector gets an element and attaches the event to **that** element (the others don't exist yet, so it's `:last`).  What you want to do is have the blur fire no matter when the element was added if it's last, `.live()` will handle that.  [See here for a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/vpNBA/).

Comment: FYI -- I think using `blur` with `live` requires using jQuery 1.4+

Comment: This looks like it could be it.  I'm not that familiar with live though, does it unbind events when the selector is no longer valid for the element?

Comment: @MiffTheFox - It listens up at the DOM root for the event bubble and executes if the selector matches, so no event actually attaches to the element itself.

Comment: Ah, okay then.  Just a concern that has just been addressed.  +1

Answer (score 1):

The selector is only evaluated when the event's assigned.  Try something like

```
$(function() {
    $(':text').live("blur", function() {
        if ($(this).is(':last')){
            $('<div class="line"><span>data: </span><input type="text"/></div>').appendTo('#lineStack');
        }
    }); 
});
```

That way, every :text gets the event (we use the [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function to make sure that it's automatically assigned to new elements when they're created), but we use the [is](http://api.jquery.com/is/) function to make sure that the one selected was really the last one.

(I also got rid of a redundant `$` call in the appendTo.  jQuery functions like appendTo can take a selector string as a parameter.)